# Magento paypal currency error

Tags: magento

Im using jamaican currency for my magento shopping cart.And i use paypal Express checkout with website payment standard.
I set up the currency in the admin panel and also the paypal settings etc are done.
My problem is when i click the button with Checkout with paypal i get the folowing error

"PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605"
I go to paypal the paypal does not support the jamaican dollar.
It would be great if some one can provide insights.

Thannks

Comment: have you solved your issue? I have been also suffering by this issue. I have done all the below steps (answerd by @chapagain). I have done upto 3rd step perfectly,I hope. But in 4th step, i have converted current currency into base currency. And echo that value and put exit comment. But again it returns to cart page. It seems that method isn't calling, I think. Could you give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the admin under *System > Configuration > Currency Setup > Currency Options* it says:

> Base currency is used for all online payment transactions. Scope is defined by the catalog price scope ("Catalog" > "Price" > "Catalog Price Scope").

So I would guess you need to set the base currency to USD so paypal can cope, and display currency to Jamaican Dollars which is what your customers will see.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Enable USD and Jamaican dollar as currency in admin (System -> GENERAL
>      -> Currency Setup)
> 2. Save currency rates (System -> Manage Currency Rates)
> 3. Rewrite `Mage_Paypal_Model_Config`
>      (app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php) class to allow Jamaican
>      dollar as supported currency, i.e. you can add your country code in
>      `$__supportedCurrencyCodes` array present on that file.
> 4. Rewrite `Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard`
>      (app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php) class to change the
>      array parameters sent to Paypal. Here, you have to edit the Jamaican
>      dollar amount to USD equivalent. Hence, sending data to Paypal as USD
>      amount. It's about modifying function `getStandardCheckoutFormFields()`.

You can rewrite/override those files by creating your custom module. OR, a simple way to override will be copying core file to local directory and editing the local file.

For example:

You can copy

> app/code/**core**/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php

to

> app/code/**local**/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php

and edit the file in **local** directory.

**Update:**

Here is a FREE Magento extension that supports PayPal payments for not supported currencies by PayPal.

https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

Comment: How can I do the last 2 steps?

Comment: Thanks @chapagain, but I can't understand what to do to those files to "Allow the Jamaican dollar".

Comment: @KlevisMiho I had done this work long time before. I have re-edited the answer with as much info as I remember now.