# Paypal gateway rejection currency not supported in magento

Tags: magento, paypal

My base currency is Chinese RMB in admin side. I do not want to change base currency and my display currency is also Chinese RMB. My payment method is PayPal standard. When I order through PayPal in front side following error occurs.

`PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details). Internal Error (#10001: Transaction failed due to internal error).`

Can anybody tell me how to fix it without changing base currency?

Comment: What Paypal API version is used? What accounts are involved (sandbox, business?)

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772976/magento-paypal-currency-error

Comment: I have used paypal standard api with live account

Answer (score 0):

This rejection is coming up from PayPal as it does not accept RMB. You need to change to the currency that accepts by PayPal. Look here for [currency accepted](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/) by PayPal.