# PayPal rejecting payment request and giving currency error in Magento

Tags: magento, paypal, payment-gateway

I know this is a very generic question but my case is different. Please read it completely.

While configuring PayPal with my Indian currency based Magento Store I am getting below error.

```
PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details). Internal Error (#10001: Transaction failed due to internal error).
```

I have tried all solutions available at [Magento paypal currency error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772976/magento-paypal-currency-error)

Base Currency in my store is - Indian Rupee

I have configured all currencies in **app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php**
and rest all settings seems to be setup perfectly. But still I am getting above error.

Please suggest where I am making mistake.

Comment: Is your issue solve?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like the Indian Rupee is a currency accepted by Paypal. Consult the [currency list](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/) to see what you can and can't accept

Comment: could you pls explain briefly?

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything to explain. PayPal does not accept the Indian Rupee

Answer (score 0):

Paypal doesn't support Indian Currency. So you need to convert your **base currency** to the accepted Currency of Paypal before proceeding to Checkout for Payment via Paypal.

Comment: can you specify which file i should change so that it accepts indian currency

Comment: @ManojChaurasia : did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have used small trick to rid this error. It is not good solution but sometime it is useful.

Go to app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout.php. Find the public function start and find below code

```
$this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal())
            ->setCurrencyCode($this->_quote->getBaseCurrencyCode())
            ->setInvNum($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId())
            ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
            ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
            ->setSolutionType($solutionType)
            ->setPaymentAction($this->_config->paymentAction);

Just replace the below code  

$this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal())
            ->setCurrencyCode('USD')
            ->setInvNum($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId())
            ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
            ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
            ->setSolutionType($solutionType)
            ->setPaymentAction($this->_config->paymentAction);
```

With this trick now you will go to paypal without any error. But you have to convert the price from Base Currency to USD.

Note: This solution is only for Paypal Express Users.

Code Taken From: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/06/paypal-gateway-has-rejected-request.html

Comment: this one is working, but the price display like, if my product Price Rs.70 means, it is displayed like $70 at my PayPal payment page. how to solve this issue?